Tensorflow Not Creating Model Correctly
found a problem following some samples from the book "AI Model and Machine Learning for Coders" from Laurence Moroney and Andrew Ng.
Summarizing the findings, the following code:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 16),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

creates a model whose summary shows the following structure:

What's the problem with the code? Why are there no parameters to train? I have created another models and they work without this issue.
Thanks,
Gus

Try building the model with an input_shape param

@jeremy how do I set input_shape in the code? I haven't used it.

For example, before compiling: model.build(input_shape=(None, 100)) or model.build(input_shape=x_train[0].shape)

thanks @jeremy! it worked, will read more about the model.build command since first time using it. thanks again

@jeremy - where can i find information about the model.build function? The method does not shows in their documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model

Add an input layer to your model, defining the shape of your dataset.Using this command tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(,) ),
this modification has enabled your model to get it's summary and weights
.Please refer to this gist
